# In Symfony migration class, get option that you entered in console migration command

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony4

I created custom Command where I added a new attribute.

```
protected function configure() : void
{
    parent::configure();

    $this
        ->setName('doctrine:migrations:generate:entitychange')
        ->addOption('db', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The database connection to use for this command.')
        ->addOption('em', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The entity manager to use for this command.')
        ->addOption('shard', null, InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED, 'The shard connection to use for this command.')
        ->addOption('entity',null,InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
            'Entity on which migration will be applied',
            'User');
}
```

Now I want to have a value of that parameter in `up()` and `down()` functions in migrations.

For example:

```
public up(Schema $schema) : void
{
   // How to get this
   $attributOfMyInputValue = $getInputValueOfParam('entity')

    if($attributOfMyInputValue  === 'someValue') {
        $sql = 'some query';
        $this->addSql($sql);
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite certain if you want to generate a migration, in which case you would have to actually extend the command you're extending, but to a far deeper degree. ... or do you want to execute migrations with that parameter, then you would be extending the wrong command and would probably override multiple places in the doctrine migrations system, which is probably something nobody really wants to do or has done (just guessing here, but I see no real reason why). - on an unrelated note https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php might work for dirty hacks.

Comment: I use a custom template and extending `AbstractMigration` for a few more options. Like in my Command class I have input variable so I can do ```$input->getArgument('entity');``` I was hoping there is some easy way to get same value in  migration class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you want to write minimal code here. So the first part of the problem is, to actually make doctrine migrations commands execute&migrate with that additional parameter/option. for that you probably have to extend both and add that parameter/option (or call them via https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html)

To pass it on, I would probably go the lazy route and just create a service that is dependency injected into both the command (via constructor) and the migrations (via container, by making the migration [container-aware](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#container-aware-migrations)) - something similar to Request's attribute bags. On the command side, I would add the parameters/options, and obviously on the migration side, read them from the same service, which can be fetched from the container.

I believe that approach entails the least amount of code, however, it's somewhat hacky. A possibly cleaner approach would be to create a new class of migrations, where those parameters are set by the migration/execute command, which probably would mean going deep into the migrations library and duplicating some of the behaviour or somehow figure out how to hook into or override the Migration execution process (which is - as far as i can tell from a quick glance - irritating, but there's probably some object you can decorate).